# Save results of geometry dash for a new telephone

Tags: data-transfer

I'm a geometry dash player, and i've passed some levels. I'm thinking about changing my smartphone. Do you know a way to store my results, and to reload them in the new telephone? I'd like to preserve my results in future...

Comment: Any answers will depend on the way the game works, so you might be best asking the developer directly. Do answer your own question if you get a useful response!

Comment: And even if not depending on how the game works, it would still depend on the Android version your device is running. Another fact you should include.

Comment: OK...I've sent a mail to the developers... It's the best way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version provides account registration, so results can be saved in the account